# Reordering sentences based on prerequisites

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say we want to work on a English As a Second Language app and we have a simple array of sentences for our users to teach them like this:

```
const sentences = [

  "that’s stupendous",
  "I'm donating a million dollars",
  "donating a million dollars to charity",
  "you just won a million dollars",
  "you just won a million dollars and are donating it to charity",
  "you just won a million dollars and are donating it to charity that’s stupendous",

  // as you see if a user learns the words of the first three sentences he/she can understand 80 percent of the last sentence

  // here is another set of sentences
  
  "he has eaten a pizza",
  "he has eaten a pizza at the party",
  "he has eaten a pizza at the party last night",

]
```

I want to rearrange the sentences into a new array so that each sentence is a prerequisites for the next sentence in the array.

**Note 1:** the above array is somehow rearranged for you to understand my meaning

**Note 2:** I have no specific rule here just imagine if you were learning English you prefer to learn which sentence before going ahead and learn the more complex one. for instance a sentence with fewer words should come earlier than a sentence with more words...

**Note 3:** I don't care about the performance of the code.

**My Failed Approach:**

I tried to loop through the sentences array split each sentence into its words and store all of them in another array like this:

```
newSentences = [

  ["that’s", "stupendous"],
  ["I'm", "donating", "a", "million", "dollars'],
  ... etc
]
```

Then I tried to count the number of exact same words for each array but here I figured out I need a more complex algorithm to determine the correct order because each sentence should be compared with all of the sentences and each movement in order of one sentence causes a change for all of the sentences...

What would be your approach and how would you solve this problem?

Comment: i understand the `he has eaten a pizza part`, but what's the order with all above(is that 1 or 2 sentences)?
what I mean is: *how is `that's stupendous` a prerequisite of `I'm donating a million dollars` and how is `donating a million dollars` a pre-requisite of `you just donated a million dollars`?*

Comment: The ordering is all about the words... as you see if a user learns the words of the first three sentences he/she can understand 80 percent of the last sentence, So I say the first three sentences are prerequisites for the last one... does it make sense...

Comment: yea that makes sense now :D

Comment: "What would be your approach and how would you solve this problem?" are poll questions and opinion questions. See the [help/dont-ask]: "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where... every answer is equally valid"

Comment: it's not a opinion base poll question, it's a problem and it's perhaps a complicated one which needs a proper algorithm to be solved... please read and understand the question first before trying to close it...

Comment: working on it.. i sorta sort it but it's a bit buggy rn.. maybe next 30 minutes i'll have answer

Comment: @SaraRee one question.. should I treat the entire array as one continuous thing or should I try to differentiate between sentences?

Comment: I haven't seen you make any attempt on what you desire. How are "I'm" and "you" supposed to be one and the same? Makes no sense to me. Maybe you want to make all the pronouns in the context of you? Use an Array of pronouns to test against.

Comment: @StackSlave according to what sara told me, it's about building up.. therefore it would have shorter sentences then longer sentences that includes those words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made 2 attempts. In both attempts I sorted the sentences in terms of which sentences had the most `matches` in terms of a `mainSentence`

Well, in this first attempt I tried to find *each* of the `mainSentence`s and try to link up sentences related with a `mainSentence`

And, in my second attempt, I look at the *whole* array as a set of linking sentences for the `mainSentence` being the sentence with the most words

Again, this is my attempt(since I think this is a little bit more than a highschool question uwu)

```js
function sentenceSort(arr){
  var toReturn=[]
  var mainSentences=[]
  var normalWords=['the','a','and'] //a tool to help to try to distinguish against sentences
  arr=arr.map(part=>part.split(' '))
  function sortBy(list,main){
    return list.sort((a,b)=>{
      let count1=0, count2=0
      a.forEach(part=>{ if(main.includes(part)){count1++} })
      b.forEach(part=>{ if(main.includes(part)){count2++} })
      return count1-count2
    })//.reverse()
  }
  function matches(sentence){
    return arr.filter(part=>part.some(word=>sentence.includes(word)&&!normalWords.includes(word)))
  }
  function mainSentence(list){
    return list.sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length)[0]
  }
  
  arr.forEach(words=>{
    let sentenceList=matches(words)
    let root=mainSentence(sentenceList)
    if(mainSentences.includes(JSON.stringify(root))){return null} //to avoid duplication
    mainSentences.push(JSON.stringify(root))
    sortBy(sentenceList,root)
    sentenceList.forEach(part=>toReturn.push(part.join(' ')))
  })
  return toReturn
}

function sentenceSort2(arr){
  var toReturn=[]
  arr=arr.map(part=>part.split(' ')).sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length)
  function sortBy(list,main){
    return list.sort((a,b)=>{
      let count1=0, count2=0
      a.forEach(part=>{ if(main.includes(part)){count1++} })
      b.forEach(part=>{ if(main.includes(part)){count2++} })
      return count1-count2
    })
  }
  function mainSentence(list){
    return list.sort((a,b)=>b.length-a.length)[0]
  }
  
  return sortBy(arr,arr[arr.length-1]).map(part=>part.join(' '))
}

console.log("Attempt 1:\n\n")
sentenceSort(sentences).forEach(part=>console.log(part))
console.log("Attempt 2:\n\n")
sentenceSort2(sentences).forEach(part=>console.log(part))
```

```html
<script>
//here is the list we work with
window.sentences = [

  "that’s stupendous",
  "I'm donating a million dollars",
  "donating a million dollars to charity",
  "you just won a million dollars",
  "you just won a million dollars and are donating it to charity",
  "you just won a million dollars and are donating it to charity that’s stupendous",
  
  "he has eaten a pizza",
  "he has eaten a pizza at the party",
  "he has eaten a pizza at the party last night",

]
</script>
```

Comment: Plus one... I'll test this as soon as I get home...

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you say on Note 2, I guess you can sort them by the length of the string on every position of the array.

So, let's suppose we have this array:

```
const sentences = [
  "I'm donating a million dollars",
  "that’s stupendous",
  "you just won a million dollars",
  "donating a million dollars to charity",
  "you just won a million dollars and are donating it to charity that’s 
  stupendous",
  "you just won a million dollars and are donating it to charity",
  "he has eaten a pizza",
  "he has eaten a pizza at the party",
  "he has eaten a pizza at the party last night",
]
```

We want to sort them based on the length of the string inside, so we could create a function for that, in this case using the ES6 array.sort function:

```
function sortArrayByLength(arr){
   let sortedArray = arr.sort((a, b) => {
     if (a.length < b.length) return -1;
     if (a.length > b.length) return 1;
     if(a.length === b.length) return 1;
   });

   return sortedArray
}
```

This will always return a new array with the shorter strings at the start of the array and the longer strings at the end of the array.

```
[
"hello",
"that’s stupendous",
"he has eaten a pizza",
"I'm donating a million dollars",
"you just won a million dollars",
"he has eaten a pizza at the party",
"donating a million dollars to charity",
"he has eaten a pizza at the party last night",
"you just won a million dollars and are donating it to charity",
"you just won a million dollars and are donating it to charity that’s stupendous"
]
```

You can change that by switching the `<` and `>` simbols in the algorithm.

Hope it works, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not the proper solution to Reordering sentences based on prerequisites, it only reorder strings based on their length...

Comment: ok, no problem. I didn't unsderstand the question then. Can you give me some examples for those prerequisites?

Comment: in the sentences array we have two sentence containing this word "stupendous" so we prefer to have the shorter sentence "that’s stupendous" before the longer one "you just won a million dollars and are donating it to charity that’s stupendous", I think note 2 is more clear now...